# Redshift- How to use previous row's calculations in current row

Tags: recursive, redshift

I am using redshift to determine projected inventory for next few week. I have receipts, current inventory and forecast.

```
ei= ei(previous row) + receipts - forecast



wk  bi  r   f   ei
1   100 20  80  40
2           50  0
3       30  15  15
4       40  14  41
5           10  31


create table ra_analytics.Test_1Test (wk int, bi int ,r int ,f int ,ei int);
insert into ra_analytics.Test_1Test values (1,  100 ,20 ,80 ,0);
insert into ra_analytics.Test_1Test values (2,  0   ,0  ,50 ,0);
insert into ra_analytics.Test_1Test values (3,  0   ,30 ,15 ,0);
insert into ra_analytics.Test_1Test values (4,  0   ,40 ,14 ,0);
insert into ra_analytics.Test_1Test values (5,  0   ,0  ,10 ,0);

select * from ra_analytics.test_1test order by wk

--Update first week of inventory
update ra_analytics.test_1test
set Ei= bi+r-f
from ra_analytics.test_1test where wk=1

--for next weeks inventory using lag function
select wk, bi, r, f, lag(ei,1) over(order by wk) +r -f as endinv
from ra_analytics.test_1test
order by wk
```

Comment: I think you need to use the lag() function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html

Comment: I tried using the windows lag function, but I don't think it supports calculations on the same field. It uses the inital values available for each field.

Answer (score 0):

You need recursive common table expresion , feature not available in redshift , try another server for this or use a loop . Lag is not referring computed columns is not helpful in this case

On another sql server it should look like this :

```
with cter as (
select r,f , wk , bi+r-f as endinv from test_1test where wk = 1 
union all 
select t.r, t.f , t.wk, c.endinv + t.r -t.f as endinv from test_1test t inner join cter c on t.wk -1  = c.wk 
)
select * from cter order by wk
```